# Getting ArrayList from firebase database without using the GenericTypeIndicator class

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way of retrieving ArrayList data from firebase database without using a generic class?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes, thanks for asking